# The "Add new document" link on Forms Library list form is messing up

Tags: web-part, infopath, list-form

It links to upload document page insead of pulling the infopath.

```
http://sitecoll/sites/0438A/_Layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={7BA9BF8D-52B5-432D-8068-B5290D2E7602}
```

But if i edit the web part and just do nothing and click apply then the link is fixed and javascript link is established for "add new document" and now infopath form opens.

Content is set to default infopath content type.

Comment: I am having this exact issue myself. 90% of the form libraries I create and add an InfoPath content type to work fine. The 'Add Document' at the bottom of the page opens a blank form to fill out. However the odd library only opens the 'upload document' popup, I cannot figure out why?

Comment: does anyone know the path "url" that we can use that invokes the "add new document" function?
I would like to add a link to the quick bar that adds a new document in my form library.

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed this issue by selecting **Full Toolbar** in Toolbar Type. The default content type attached to the form library gets opened up and it no more redirects you to uplaod a document...

that is great.... it is worked with me

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. Thank for the answer.

Comment: ...Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are working with SharePoint 2010. Just wanted to point out on a side note that Forms Library forms and List forms are really two different things. A List form results when you are on a standard SharePoint list and click the button to design the form using InfoPath. I presume you are referring to Forms Library forms.  The "Add document" link at the bottom of a forms library actually goes to the upload link by default.  I'm not a fan of this as it seems most people would want it to open a blank form template.  To open a blank template, you need to go to the Documents tab on the ribbon and choose the "New Document" link.

Answer (score 0):

After days of looking for a work around I have found a fix:

Read the blog post [Add a ‘Create New Document’ link to a page](http://www.novolocus.com/2009/03/04/add-a-create-new-document-link-to-a-page/)

Comment: Gavin, posting to external sites are ok as long as you remember to include in your answer the solution that the external link contains. We like to keep the answers in our site (and external links tend to die)